# Custom Shortcut for npm/npx command not working

Tags: 20.04, shortcuts, npm

## Problem

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with gnome 3.36.8 and I’m trying to set up a shortcut that should run the command `npx mira refresh`. This should refresh an external monitor. This command works fine in a terminal and doesn't need any user input, but my costum shortcut is not working.
`npm` was installed using `nvm`.

## What I've tried

I tried setting up the shortcut with the gnome shortcut manager (in Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts), without success. Rebooting didn't help.
I tried also:
`npm exec -c "mira refresh"` since `npx` is a short command for `npm exec`. The shortcut was Ctrl + R.

I checked the PATH variable to be sure that it is pointing to the correct path and it is (first path of the output).

```
> echo $PATH
/home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v18.3.0/bin:/home/myName/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

> which npx
/home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v18.3.0/bin/npx
```

I also wanted to check if they might be conflicting versions.

```
> dpkg -l npx
dpkg-query: no packages found matching npx

>locate npx
/home/myName/.npm/_npx
[...]
/home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v18.3.0/bin/npx
[...]
```

Also I get an error in the logs when executing the shortcut (but not the command in a terminal):

```
> cat /var/log/syslog | grep "npx"
sh: 1: exec: npx: not found
```

## Questions

1. Aren't the shortcuts working with the same PATH variable? Why is the command running normally in the terminal but fails when executed through a shortcut?
2. How can I fix my problem? Any ideas?

Thanks for your time and for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the installation of `npm` via `nvm`.

From https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2025 :

> The cause is that nvm installs itself to .bashrc. It seems that .bashrc never gets evaluated if you start your desktop and run an app from the desktop environment directly (ie: clicking on an icon, autostart, etc). This results in the app having an environment with a PATH variable which lacks the appropriate node path.

I had to move these lines :

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

to .profile and it worked.